# Javascript toggle animation on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am new to Javascript and trying to figure out the best way to achieve the following.

I have this page set up, consisting of the HTML and CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/59ykx03y/3/

What I need to do is when the user clicks on the image container, both h2 tags need to animate to the middle/center on top of the image so it reads Lorem Ipsum in one line. I also need to change the text colour to white instead of blue. When the user clicks again, the text color will revert back to the original blue, and the position will revert back to how it was at first. So I guess I need to toggle this.

I then need to figure out a way to prevent this code from running in viewports that are less than 920px as the layout is different. Ideally I would want the user to tap on the image on these smaller screen devices and the text would animate to display Lorem & Ipsum in their own separate lines on top of the image.

I initially tried to add a "**click**" eventListener, and running an **if/else** statement to test.

```
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(lorem.style.color === "blue") {
    lorem.style.color = '#ffffff';
  }
  else {
    lorem.style.color = 'blue';
  }
});
```

But I feel there is a much easier way to approach this without repeating myself.

Please note I have to use vanilla JS for this and not jQuery.

I look forward to your solutions!

Comment: Personally, this feels like a situation where I'd just add/remove a class using JS and handle all of the style changes with CSS for that class.

Comment: @DBS thanks and I agree, just struggling with writing the JS, and then I don't know how to approach this when scaling the browser below 920px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q:
" I also need to change the text colour to white instead of blue. When the user clicks again, the text color will revert back to the original blue, and the position will revert back to how it was at first."

A:

//add this class to your CSS

```
.hdr-color-white{
  color: white;
}
```

//add to your current event handler

```
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  lorem.classList.toggle("hdr-color-white");
  ipsum.classList.toggle("hdr-color-white");
});
```

Q:
"I then need to figure out a way to prevent this code from running in viewports that are less than 920px as the layout is different. Ideally I would want the user to tap on the image on these smaller screen devices and the text would animate to display Lorem & Ipsum in their own separate lines on top of the image."

A:
To prevent the code from running in viewports less than 920px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
  hdr-color-white{
    /*empty*/
  }
}
```

You can also test for the width via the window object's window.screen.width method.

To relocate the Lorem and Ipsum text, float them to the desired position using CSS via the position, top, left, and transform properties.
Check this link for more detailed explanation on positioning.
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

When at a desired location you can cause the slide in effect using 
    transform: translateX(value);  //can be toggled if added to a class

Comment: Thank you, i managed to get it all to work, and learnt how to use classList.toggle in the process! I didn't even have to write an If/Else statement either.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    lorem.style.marginLeft = "5%"
    lorem.style.marginTop = "5%"
    lorem.style.color = lorem.style.color ? 'white' : 'blue';
});
```

If you're not familiar with it that `?` in the last line is called a ternary operator.  It's sort of like a mini if/else: `a ? b : c` means "b if a, else c".

Comment: Thanks for your response, this does indeed make the blue text white upon click. However it doesn't allow toggling between the two colours. For example after the 2nd click, the colour would need to be blue again and go back to its original position. Any idea how I can animate both text to the middle with a toggle also?

Comment: Change the ternary to consider the current color: `lorem.style.color = lorem.style.color === 'blue' ? 'white' : 'blue';`